# Disable/Remove default !important declarations in elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a CSS conflict going on with a major plugin in my wordpress site. The plugin maker found it handy to add !important declarations throughout all their styling sheets. From a developer's perspective; this is a disaster. In their defense they want to cover all themes that are using !important declarations, so it looks consistent. I do not agree, so I need a solution.

What happens is that my premium theme, who's not using those declarations, cannot override the styling. I have some solutions to remove certain classes by jQuery.

But there is a problem which cannot be resolved by removing classes. For example, the anchor`:hover` is default as `border: none !important` by the plugin. But I would like to see is that the anchor:hover border option is actually applied via the theme settings. The applied CSS is this (be aware that the `.plugin` class is not applied in the anchor, just from a CSS file):

`.plugin a { border: none !important; }`

Is there any way I can disable certain class combinations from the DOM? I'm happy to have this done with `php` or `jQuery`. Something like: `.plugin is not applied to anchor` I have no idea how to resolve this.

Comment: I have tried to remove the CSS file with jQuery, but that eliminates also some styling which are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is just a case of overwriting the css with a better specified css line.

For example if the code is:

```
.plugin a::hover { border: none !important; }
```

You can overwrite this by doing:

```
body .plugin a::hover { border: 1px solid grey !important; }
```

Because you have added the element **body** to your css line it adds extra specificity meaning it overwrites the plugins css. You unfortunately have to use !important, as !important throws regular specificity ruling out the window (bad plugin creator).

[More on css specificity here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is an alternative solution, but I would like the Theme  settings to take the anchor styling. Because I'm aiming for a consistent way of styling.

Comment: Sorry my answer was provided based on updating your theme so that your theme is overwriting, if that's out the window then there's not a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need any of the styles provided by the plugin? If not then it might be worth looking at dequeueing the plugin styles altogether and just adding your own styles where the theme doesn't cover it.

If you find out the registered name of the stylesheet (should be in the style tag) you can dequeue it with something like:

```
function remove_push_plugin_styles() {
   wp_dequeue_style( 'plugin-stylesheet' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'remove_pushy_plugin_styles', 1000 );
```

Answer (score -1):

You aren't able to edit an iframe's content, true. But the iframe's itself still belongs to your page, and you can edit the attributes. I just tested and was able to do something similar to:

```
var i = $('div.item iframe');
// Did the selector work?
console.log(i.length);
i.removeAttr('width');
i.removeAttr('height');
```

That being said, using !important in this situation is not bad. If you're worried about CSS maintenance, leave a comment that the !important is overriding the element's attributes. !important is often demonized, but in this case it is a valid use to increase the specificity of your CSS.

The advantage of doing it in CSS is that it will apply before your JavaScript is loaded, so you won't get a split second of those attributes and styles applying before the JavaScript removes the styles.

Comment: iframe? Where do you see this in my question?